# Good xcode alternative for writing objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, macos

As Xcode 4 is likely to stay as slow as it is now, are there any editors out there that are code aware and good with objective-C?

I will not stop using xcode, it still has great features but just for the writing of the code.

Comment: Why do you need an alternative of xCode ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, xcode will probably stay as slow as it is now, it lags too much.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your particular machine.  Xcode 4 is one of the better IDEs available on the Mac IMO.

Comment: @Doomspork its a good IDE, but the performance is bad. Its not my particular machine, its do-able but I hate it how slow it has become compared to xcode 3. It even lacks good syntax coloring, if you fill in a random name it will color it as an instance variable and will give you an error, great! xcode 3 didn't do that

Comment: @Jhaliya because it is some sort of cruel practical joke on the part of Apple

Comment: I don't see the problems that you are seeing with XCode 4, neither the perceived slowness, nor incorrect syntax colouring. So you may have a special situation. I suggest you take it up with Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is:

- [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (commercial)
- [Kod](http://kodapp.com/) (open source)
- [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/) (commercial)
- [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) (open source)
- [Smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/) (open source)
- [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) (commercial)
- [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (free)

You could even use one of these with the appropriate plugins:

- [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) (commercial)
- [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com) (commercial)

…just to name a few.

Comment: I wouldn't use Kod in a production environment, it just crashes way too much and the syntax highliting often gets confused and highlights garbage.

Comment: Is smultron opensource again? Seen it in the mac app store for 3.99

Comment: Well, on GitHub there are quite a bunch of repos for Smultron albeit a bit dated (>6months).

Comment: sorry, but you listed text editors. I don't see any of these as a replacement for Xcode. They are just text editors with syntax highlight. A real replacement for Xcode will be a huge success, as Xcode 4 stinks and is a 10 fold back step comparing to Xcode 3.

Comment: @DigitalRobot: Well, that's what OP asked for, as you might have noticed by actually reading his/her question. Lemme quote: "are there any editors out there that are code aware and good with objective-C?" Yup, there are. See my answer. OP did not ask for IDEs and even explicitly mentioned being looking for alternatives "just for the writing of the code", not the IDE part of Xcode. Had OP asked for IDEs I'd have listed [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/index.jsp). AppCode however is a OSX UX train-wreck. Compared to AppCode, Xcode 4 is a godsend.

Answer (score 9):

JetBrains is working on AppCode - http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

It's in beta and freely available.  Worth a look if you searching for alternatives.

Comment: AppCode is incredibly full-featured, fast, and stable. To dismiss it on the grounds of the platform it's built on is just silly.

Comment: Has anyone here had any long-term experience with this IDE?
I'm curious about it, but don't want to jump on the bandwagon unless I know it's worth jumping on.

Comment: my answer was june 2, 2011.  i am writing this comment on may 12, 2012.  long story short, i've been using appcode fulltime since december.  after being a long time xcode user, i had to sort of 'force' myself to use it for a week before i got hooked.  as an editor, its very power and fully featured.   remember its not a replacement to xcode but a enhancement rather.